# Use Toolbar as ActionBar in ALL Activities without programmatically doing it in each Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I've placed the following code in onCreate() to set a toolbar I use in each Activity as the ActionBar:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

This works fine and shows the back arrow and title in each Activity, and is necessary because we add custom content to our ToolBar, but it's messy and annoying to have to do this in each Activity.

What's the best way to achieve this behavior without the duplication? Can it be done in styles?

Answer (score 1):

You should create Base Activity like this :

```
public class Base extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView icon1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    initToolbar()
}


public void  initToolbar() {
    .
    .
    .
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    if (showIcon1())
        icon1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        icon1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public boolean showIcon1(){
    return  true;
}
```

And other activity :

```
public class OtherActivity extends Base {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}

@Override
public boolean showIcon1() {
    return false;
}<br>
```

Hope this Help.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this implementation is that icon1 in this case is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if "best" but if you really want that in all your activities you have two choices:

1. Inheritance: A very common Android/Java approach is to subclass `Activity` and then use that as your base. E.g.:

   ```
    public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setupToolbar();
      }

      private void setupToolbar() {
       // do whatever you need to do
      }
    }

   public class YourFancyClass extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Do anything you need to. The toolbar is set by the base class.
    }
   }
   ```

That's one option (very popular)

2. Plan B would be to use Composition, mostly preferred in the iOS side, yet still very valid (and sometimes more appropriate, a discussion we're not having now) :)

Basically have an object that is capable of setting your toolbar. Create an interface that can represent that behavior. Have an implementation of such behavior (Java usually calls them `XxxxxImpl` and have that interface and implementation passed onto the activities that need it.

Sounds more complicated, but it's very clean and clear once you got it all together.